# Install custom catkin package on Raspbian

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have some problem. I made a custom package on ros kinetic (ubuntu 16.04) previously and is working fine. Recently I am trying to use it on a Raspberry Pi3 (Raspbian).

I have successfully installed ROS following official tutorial so actually I have a ros_catkin_ws directory with necessary sources compiled. I also manged to install a release package (p2os_driver) from github using ros-install, wstool, catkin_make_isolated.

So now I have my catkin package test (which contains launch and src directories with packgae.xml and CMake). On Ubuntu this folder was located in catkin_ws and all I had to do was catkin_make, source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash.

So my question is, how can I import this package into my new installation on Raspbian ? I tried several things, copying it in ros_catkin_ws/src then catkin_make_isolated this specific package, tried to make an overlay catkin workspace (without amstering it at all so maybe I did it wrong) so I can use catkin_make (but this only get me a "can't find rosout" when doing "roslaunch test test.launch").

Maybe I got it wrong when using "source" also. Currently I have ROS_PACKAGE_PATH set to "/opt/ros/kinetic/share". Or I missed a catkin_init_workspace somehow.

Thanks for your help.

Edit :

Thanks for answering. Still in trouble though.
When running `catkin_make` in my second worspace (`catkin_ws`), I got this (after having sourced `ros_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`):

```
    +++ processing catkin package: 'test'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(test)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/p2os_driver/cmake/p2os_driverConfig.cmake:148 (message):
  Project 'test' tried to find library 'p2os_driver'.  The library is
  neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
  'p2os_driver'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing
  its code is included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  test/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
```

However `p2os_driver` is, I think, properly built in main workspace (`ros_catwin_ws`) since I got no error doing :

```
sudo ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated -j1 --install --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --pkg p2os_driver
```

Is there something I am doing wrong with dependencies ? I created "test" package in `catkin_ws` doing

```
catkin_create_pkg test rospy p2os_driver nav_msgs tf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291182/install-custom-catkin-package-on-raspbian/) by [r00t8](https://answers.ros.org/users/33691/r00t8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:\

> Project 'test' tried to find library 'p2os_driver'.

could you show the `CMakeLists.txt` of the `test` pkg that you created? Please omit all the boilerplate comments (lines starting with `#`), they are not needed.

**Comment by [r00t8](https://answers.ros.org/users/33691/r00t8/) on 2018-05-16**:
project(test)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
nav_msgs
p2os_driver
rospy
tf
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Overlaying (or *chaining*) is what would probably be the most natural (and efficient) way to do this.

I would:

1. make sure you've not `source`d anything
2. `source` your current `ros_catkin_ws` (either `devel` or `install`, depending on how you set things up)
3. go to the root of your new catkin ws
4. run `catkin_make`

This should build just the new package, while making use of the other workspace as the *underlay* that contains all the base ROS packages.

After building, `source` the `devel/setup.bash` of your new workspace and everything should work.

PS: I've left out the step making sure all dependencies of your new package are actually present on your Pi. If they aren't, you'll need to fix that before trying to build.

---

Edit:

> When running `catkin_make` in my second worspace (`catkin_ws`), I got this (after having sourced `ros_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`)

From your later comment you appear to have an install space under `/opt/ros/kinetic`. I would recommend you `source` that, not the `devel` space of your underlying workspace.

re: cannot find `p2os_driver`: if you open a new terminal (make sure to not auto-source anything), source `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` and then do a `rospack find p2os_driver`, does that return successfully?

---

Edit2: I believe you're running into this issue because the `CMakeLists.txt` of the `p2os_driver` package is faulty.

It has this (from [here](https://github.com/allenh1/p2os/blob/b9e56c053d3d985489b747f57577f08b861e4826/p2os_driver/CMakeLists.txt#L15-L19)):

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES p2os_driver
  CATKIN_DEPENDS p2os_msgs nav_msgs roscpp geometry_msgs diagnostic_updater tf std_msgs kdl_parser
)
```

Notice the `LIBRARIES p2os_driver` bit.

That makes Catkin believe that this package produces a library called `libp2os_driver.so`, and it will export that information to whoever `find_package(catkin .. COMPONENTS p2os_driver ..)`. This is passed to CMake, and it will start looking for that library.

But `p2os_driver` does not build any libraries, only a single executable binary and that is called `p2os_driver` ([here](https://github.com/allenh1/p2os/blob/b9e56c053d3d985489b747f57577f08b861e4826/p2os_driver/CMakeLists.txt#L27)). That is most likely the cause of your problems.

For now: remove (or comment) the `LIBRARIES p2os_driver` line from the `catkin_package(..)` statement in the `CMakeLists.txt` of the `p2os_driver` package. You'll have to rebuild the package, and have Catkin install it to your install space as well.

And please report this in an issue over at [allenh1/p2os/issues](https://github.com/allenh1/p2os/issues).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r00t8](https://answers.ros.org/users/33691/r00t8/) on 2018-05-16**:
Yes, gives me `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/p2os_driver`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
Ok. Can you try what you did earlier, but now after `source`-ing `/opt/ros/kinetic` as you did just now?

**Comment by [r00t8](https://answers.ros.org/users/33691/r00t8/) on 2018-05-16**:
Exactly the same error that previously when `source`-ing `~/ros_catkin_ws/devel/`

**Comment by [r00t8](https://answers.ros.org/users/33691/r00t8/) on 2018-05-16**:
Editing `CMakeLists.txt` from `p2os_driver` package worked. Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
Could you please post a link to the issue over at `allenh1/p2os` so we keep things connected?